# Discord Buttons Interaction Failed, But The Bot Responded Normally, Any Way To Remove The Interaction Failed Text under the button?

Tags: discord.js

So i tried to make a discord bot which send embed and buttons, when i used the buttons, the bot is responding to it normally, but under the button, there was a text saying "interaction failed", here is the code

```
    const akiLangEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${message.author.tag}`)
      .setDescription(`Please Select Your Language`)
      .setColor(client.config.embedcolor)
      .setTimestamp()
    const lang1 = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
                .setStyle("SUCCESS")
                .setLabel("English")
                .setCustomId("en"),

            new MessageButton()
                .setStyle("SUCCESS")
                .setLabel("Indonesia")
                .setCustomId("id"),

            new MessageButton()
                .setStyle("SUCCESS")
                .setLabel("Japan")
                .setCustomId("ja")
        )
    const lang2 = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
                .setStyle("SUCCESS")
                .setLabel("Germany")
                .setCustomId("gr"),

            new MessageButton()
                .setStyle("SUCCESS")
                .setLabel("France")
                .setCustomId("fr"),

            new MessageButton()
                .setStyle("SUCCESS")
                .setLabel("Chinese")
                .setCustomId("zh")
        )
      const langPick = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [akiLangEmbed], components: [lang1, lang2]})
      const filter = (interaction) => {
            if (interaction.user.id === message.author.id) return true;
            return interaction.reply({
                content: `Only ${message.author.tag} can use this interaction!`,
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        };

        const collector = langPick.createMessageComponentCollector({
            filter,
            componentType: "BUTTON",
            time: 60000 * 5
        })

        collector.on("collect", async (interaction) => {
          if(interaction.customId === "en") {
            await akinator(message, {
              language: "en",
              useButtons: true,
              embedColor: client.config.embedcolor
            })
          }
          if(interaction.customId === "id") {
            await akinator(message, {
              language: "id",
              useButtons: true,
              embedColor: client.config.embedcolor
            })
          }
          if(interaction.customId === "ja") {
            await akinator(message, {
              language: "ja",
              useButtons: true,
              embedColor: client.config.embedcolor
            })
          }
        })
```

and yes i have imported **all** packages needed at the top of the code using **const and require**, any **Help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to defer your interaction. Paste this line on the first line of your collector.on event.

```
await interaction.deferUpdate();
```